# AWS Elastic Beanstalk PHP installation - session time out

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've observed that my PHP pages in the production environment session times out but unable to figure out what determines the duration of time out.

I use AWS ElasticBeanstalk to run the PHP code.

I'd like to find out

- what is the session time set to and where is it set typically?
- how I can programmatically control the time out from the PHP layer

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If the session timeout is not explicitly set through the code, then you can check the default value set in the `php.ini` file for `session.gc_maxlifetime` which specifies the number of seconds after which data will be seen as 'garbage' and potentially cleaned up. Garbage collection may occur during session start (depending on session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor). Defaults to 1440 (24 minutes).

References:-

[session.gc_maxlifetime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime)

[PHP - How to implement session lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270960/12326605)

Comment: The instance is loaded in AWS elastic beanstalk. how would I find the php.ini file and its content in such cases?

Comment: If you don't have access to the instances, then you can use `phpinfo();` in the code to show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL.